# Angular - Sidebar not to show in Login but to show in Dashboard - Angular Routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How to hide sidebar in login page?

How can I open login page first without sidebar and then after successful login will redirect on dashboard of template in Angular 4.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Use a `Shell Component`.

Comment: Im using template for my angular project where i need a separate login page without sidebar, but in my template there is sidebar in each and every page, so i want solution for how can i hide sidebar, or how can i create a separate component for login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to design a Shell Component(suggested by [Deborah Kurata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk) in [this ngConf talk](https://youtu.be/LaIAHOSKHCQ?t=124)) which will house your View After the user logs in.

The template of this Shell Component will house the Side Bar. The template of this Shell Component will also have a `router-outlet` for internal routing.

So your `Routes` config will look something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      ...
      {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewPostComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: PlaceholderComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Template for the Shell Component:

```
<!--Markup for your Sidebar here-->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!--This router outlet is for Components that will load through child routing-->
```

Template for your App Component:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sample-routing-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.