# Conditional layout in Angular with two navbars

Tags: angular, layout, responsive-design

I'm currently hitting a layout issue in Angular and I'm hoping there's a quick (quicker lol) fix that I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Here's a visual representation of how my layout is currently structured. (The little black bar at the top is just a label for the design)

[image]

Within the HTML, `app.component.html`, it looks like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

The issue I'm running into is that I now have one page within my application that completely breaks this layout model and the Angular `router-outlet` structure I showed above. Here's the visual.

[image]

As you can see, there's a new navbar to the left that takes up all of the vertical height. The old navbar now shrinks to the remaining width with the `router-outlet` content below that which also shrinks to the remaining width (they’re both full-width in the first image even if there’s some margin on the sides).

There's already many views within the application and this is the only view that has this type of layout.

Everything still needs to be responsive and I can't think of an easy fix without completely re-doing most of the layout to essentially be two navbar first, with the navbar and content expanding to fill the remaining width if the secondary navbar isn't visible.

There's some really hacky ways around this but that makes responsive a nightmare and I'd prefer to avoid that. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Sidebar not to show in Login but to show in Dashboard - Angular Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793170/angular-sidebar-not-to-show-in-login-but-to-show-in-dashboard-angular-routin)

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thanks, I'll take a look at this and see if I can make it work. I'll report back later.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I actually have a Sample Working StackBlitz attached. That'll help you to see it working. Do let me know if there's any concern and I can add an answer here for you.

Comment: These are good solutions for a "one-off" problem, which may work for you. However, if it seems like your issue will occur again or in a different way (maybe your app will change so that now some pages have two navs, some one, maybe some have none) I'd look into named outlets. https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/#Create_Named_Router_Outlet